# Selenium IE 11 test on Jenkins Master Server Using nunit3-console.exe

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, nunit, internet-explorer-11

I have a Selenium IE 11 test written in C# that runs perfectly when run locally in Debug or Release. this code is deployed to a Win 10 box with Jenkins (NO SLAVES). The Jenkins "Build" is configured to build the code, copy the test.dll to a folder and then call nunit3-console.exe to run the test. the Jenkins Service is also configured with a Domain User Account as a Service Logon Account.

I can logon to the win 10 box as the (Jenkins) domain user, and open a cmd window and run the following with no problem at all

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Prod Login>"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" C:\Prod
>   Login\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll

but if you try to "Build" the solution via Jenkins Web UI, it has a problem during the Nunit test finding some elements after it does a few clicks and a submit.

I know the IE configuration is rock solid like I said the test runs fine in a command window when logged in as the (Jenkins) Domain account

here is the error I get:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException :
>   Assert.Fail failed. **ProcessError*** By.XPath:
>   //input[@placeholder='Username'], Following element not found:
>   By.XPath: //input[@placeholder='Username'], Timed out after 75
>   seconds;

again I know its not the locator, it works with By.Id or By.Xpath in the command window, AND my Chrome, and Firefox test with the SAME code base just a different WebDriver all work.

I can't help but think it has something to do with the Identity that's being used by Jenkins and or Nunit

any help is greatly appreciated!!!

> ** UPDATE 
>   I just tried to configure a Jenkins "Slave" with the service account
>   running as the Jenkins Domain user, no luck still...

Comment: If these are NUnit tests, why are you getting an AssertFailedException from the VS test tools. Are you using both frameworks in one test assembly?

Comment: the assert fail comes from not being able to locate the element, and timing out the defined "Wait" time.  Nunit is nothing more than the container from which the test is run, The WebDirvers and the Extension frameworks are from Selenium.

Comment: So Selenium uses VSTest Assertions even when running from NUnit? I was not aware of that. BTW, I'd answer if I could but you are using two products I don't uses. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to post just a comment, but I have a debug suggestion. I know what you are saying with "the selector works fine", so I am not suggesting that the selector is wrong in any way. However, I do suggest having the test spew the page source just before the failing command. Driver.PageSource. And post it somewhere you can get to it.

That way, you can identify that the driver definitely sees the elements in the DOM that it has available to it.

This will help eliminate a whole slew of potential problems. There is always the possibility that the driver is simply not seeing the html that these selectors would point to, even though we can see it with our own two eyes.

Comment: I had the same thought early on, and actually did look a the dom, the element is there. the issue at heart is when the code is executed by Jenkins, it fails, run it in a command window as the "designated" Jenkins Domain user, it works no problem.

It has to be the IE driver and the way it has to configured just so, or clicks, data entry, etc at the  x, y axis dont work.

Comment: So are you running the test locally by command line, or Visual Studios? 

If you are running the code via command line, are you sure it is the same test execution binary launching it? I've had issues when running dotnet test through different versions between my dev machine and Jenkins. Although, even that should not really affect driver execution like this. 

Is it feasible to try chrome as well, and see if the issue is definitely driver specific? That could at least rule out Jenkins.

Comment: Also, do you get your IEDriver.exe from Nuget, via a package restore, or do you supply it to your Jenkins machine from source control, or is it saved on the Jenkins machine in some static location?